# Animation across different iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, autolayout

How would you animate across multiple iPhone Screens? Let me explain a bit.

So, currently I had an animation where three buttons spread out with a `spring animation`. I already set auto layout and the whole project had no errors or risks.

In my case, which is terrible, I used `CGPoint`
So, it would be like...

```
animationCodeMethod {

button1.center = CGPoint(x: , y: )
button2.center = CGPoint(x: , y: )
button3.center = CGPoint(x: , y: )

}
```

My goal of the animation was for three buttons that appeared stacked on each other, to slide out a couple pixels away from each other when executed.

**o //Three stacked**

**executed: ->o-o-o**

I know the CGPoint method is terrible.

What works on one device like the iPhone 5, looks completely different on iPhone 6 or 6 plus. I know I'm supposed to use auto layout in code, but literally have no clue. How would you set it up so the animation works across all screens? The CGPoint is very pixel specific. So though it looks okay on one screen size, on another, the resolution changes (more pixels) which makes a different result.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so it's hard to give you a general answer.

Using hard-coded values is a case of using "magic numbers", which is bad.

You should set up constraints the set the center position of your buttons, link outlets to those constraints, and then manipulate them in code.

If you want to distribute your buttons, write code that figures out the width of the superview, then divides up the space to place the buttons evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using AutoLayout, try using NSLayoutConstraints. Link two up to your ViewController; one will be the horizontal spacing between button1 and button2 and the other will be the horizontal spacing between button2 and button3. In the animation:

```
button1And2Contraint.constant = distanceBetween
button2And3Contraint.constant = distanceBetween
```

It would be wise to get the width of the superview and set "distanceBetween" accordingly.